# Rails why is .css.scss and .html.haml necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, sass, haml

Surely Sprockets has enough info if a file is named x.scss and y.haml to assume that by default it should be rendered as css and html (the same applies with CoffeeScript)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is used to indicate clearly you want some kind of file.

This may be obvious most of the time so you can skip it.

Actually, this is really needed when you serve different types of views: `.pdf`, `.html` for instance. In this case, you have to use `.pdf.haml`, `.html.haml`

Same for `coffee` and `scss`, I never use `.js.coffee`, always use `.coffee` directly.